# Could I use an indefinite article before "head" after "in"?

Tags: prepositions, articles

Could I say "in a head"? I did not find this case over the internet. For example, Oxford Dictionary explains a headache like "a continuous pain in **the** head". Why this aricle is used here?

Comment: It's usual to use _the_ in many phrases referring to parts of the anatomy.  "He was wounded in the arm." "a slap across the face" and the idiom for a nuisance "a pain in the neck" (polite) or "in the arse/ass" (less polite).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a use of the **definite generic** article; we mean "in heads in general".  Saying "a pain in **a** head" implies that there are many possible heads you have that might have pains in, because the indefinite article means "one nonspecific member of all X".

We tend to use the definite generic for body parts, like

> [(Corns and calluses) most often develop on the feet and toes](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/corns-and-calluses/symptoms-causes/syc-20355946)

(even though you have multiple feet and toes that could develop corns)

> [Cardiomyopathy – a disease of the heart muscle](https://www.betterhealth.vic.gov.au/health/ConditionsAndTreatments/heart-disorders-acquired-children)

(even though there are many hearts in the world that could develop cardiomyopathy).  Think of the definite generic here as "the X *that you have*".