# By <noun> vs By <gerund>

Tags: grammar, prepositions, usage, gerunds

Can "by" be used with a noun to mean "because of"?

> By fear, blood vessels become weak

If that is wrong, can "by" be used with a gerund to mean the same?

> By fearing, blood vessels become weak

What are the other best ways to write the above sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the **by** examples in @ronald-sole's answer provide a **means** of achieving a goal. *Reading* is a thing you do when you want to *broaden your horizons*.

A verb like *cause* may be what you want:

> Fear causes blood vessels to weaken.

(*Weaken* is slightly more idiomatic than *become weak*.)

In the scientific/medical genre, it might be more stylistically appropriate to write:

> Fear causes weakening of the blood vessels.

This uses the gerund *weakening*, because symptoms are often expressed as nouns in medical writing. *The* blood vessels because we assume there is some generic patient who can be expected to have blood vessels ([definite generic](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/291604/139225)).

Answer (score 1):

**By** can be used with both nouns and gerunds to indicate cause - although your examples imply that blood vessels themselves fear, which makes little sense.

However, you can say things such as:

**By effort we advance** and
**By reading we broaden our horizons.**